# Extract fields and values from text line using C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file

I am reading in a text file with lines of the format:

```
date    =20170422,line    =10,index   =3,field   =partType,lock    =productCode1,bookmark=2/19/56,
```

I need to extract the name of the field (date, line, index, etc.) and its corresponding value into `char field[]` and `char value[]` variables.  If necessary, I am allowed to modify the format of the lines.

My initial thinking was to use while loops and check for `=` and `,` characters but it was getting messy and it seems like there may be a cleaner way.

Comment: Use `strchr`, `getline()` and strings instead of pointer to char arrays

Comment: The "clean" way would be to use a proper parser like Boost.Spirit. Otherwise for such a simple format, splitting on "=", then splitting the fragments on ",", and then iterating should do the trick.

Comment: In other words: How do I tokenize a character string? Asked and answered a bazillion times. Downvoted based on lack of research.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the below example. Split the string by commas using getline from your file, then split use an istringstream to and getline to split it again by an equals sign.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
int main()
{
        std::ifstream file("test.txt");
        std::string wholeLine, partOfLine;
        while(std::getline(file, wholeLine, ',')) {
                std::istringstream wholeLineSS(wholeLine);
                while(std::getline(wholeLineSS, partOfLine, '=')) {
                        std::cout<<partOfLine<<std::endl;
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The program I post here extracts the parameters from one or more strings which are formatted as you require. The function `extract` extracts all the parameters contained in a string (of the format you specified) and insert their names and values in a structure (`struct sParms`) array.

You may compile the program as extract and execute it at the system prompt as:

> username: ./extract "date    =20170422,line    =10,index   =3,field
>   =partType,lock    =productCode1,bookmark=2/19/56,"

The output will be the following:

> ```
> [date]=[20170422]
> [line]=[10]
> [index]=[3]
> [field]=[partType]
> [lock]=[productCode1]
> [bookmark]=[2/19/56]
> ```

You may execute the program with more than one string:

> username: ./extract "date    =20170422,line    =10,index   =3,field
>   =partType,lock    =productCode1,bookmark=2/19/56," "yes=1, no=0"

The output will be the following:

> ```
> [date]=[20170422]
> [line]=[10]
> [index]=[3]
> [field]=[partType]
> [lock]=[productCode1]
> [bookmark]=[2/19/56]
>
> [yes]=[1]
> [no]=[0]
> ```

In the following line there's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libgen.h>

//Parameters: date    =20170422,line    =10,index   =3,field   =partType,lock    =productCode1,bookmark=2/19/56,
#define SEPARATOR       ','
#define ASSIGNEMENT     '='

typedef struct sParms {
    char * fieldName;
    char * fieldValue;
} tsParms;

int loadString(char *to, const char *from);

int extract(tsParms **oparms, const char *inb);

// Retrieve buffer length
int loadString(char *to, const char *from)
{
    int len=0;

    while(*from<=32 && *from!=SEPARATOR && *from!=ASSIGNEMENT)
        from++;

    // Get the string value
    while(*from>32 && *from!=SEPARATOR && *from!=ASSIGNEMENT) {
        *(to+len++)=*from;
        ++from;
    }

    *(to+len++)=0;

    return len;
}

int extract(tsParms ** oparms, const char *inb)
{
    int cnt=0,j;
    const char * end, *equ, *start;
    char * buff;
    tsParms * parms;

    if (inb == NULL || strlen(inb) == 0 || oparms == NULL)
        return 0;

    // It counts the number of parms
    end=strchr(inb,ASSIGNEMENT);
    while(end) {
        cnt++;
        end=strchr(end+1,ASSIGNEMENT);
    }

    if (!cnt)
        return 0;

    /* Doing some considerations we may assume that the memory to use to store
     * fields name and values is the same of the input string (inb)
     *
     * The space to store the pointers is cnt * sizeof(tsParms *).
     */

    j=cnt * sizeof(tsParms) + strlen(inb);
    parms = malloc(j+1);
    memset(parms,0,j+1);

    buff = (char *)(parms+cnt); // The memory area where we can save data!

    start=inb;end=start;cnt=0;
    do {
        end=strchr(start,SEPARATOR);
        equ=strchr(start,ASSIGNEMENT);

        if (equ) {
            //Get the field name
            parms[cnt].fieldName=buff;
            buff+=loadString(buff,start);

            //Get the field value
            start=equ+1;
            parms[cnt].fieldValue=buff;
            buff+=loadString(buff,start);

            cnt++;
        }

        if (end)
            start=end+1;
    } while(end);

    *oparms = parms;

    return cnt;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i,j,cnt=0,retval=0;
    tsParms * parms=NULL;

    if (argc<2) {
        printf("Usage: %s \"string-1\" [\"string-2\" ...\"string-n\"]\n",basename(argv[0]));
        return 1;
    }

    for(i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        cnt=extract(&parms, argv[i]);

        if (cnt!=0 && parms!=NULL) {
            for(j=0;j<cnt;j++) {
                printf("[%s]=[%s]\n",parms[j].fieldName,parms[j].fieldValue);
            }
            puts("");

            free((void *)parms);
        } else {
            retval=1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return retval;
}
```